# svelte-navigator not working with latest release of svelte

Tags: svelte

I was wondering if anyone is also having trouble installing svelte-navigator. Before the latest update of Svelte (4.2.8) this worked fine but with the latest update I got an error that svelte-navigator needs Svelte v3. The issue is that I have other libraries that need Svelte 4.2.8 so I cannot simply use an older version of it. Anybody found a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue following a Udemy course.  Curious on the work around for this.   When looking at svelte-navigation it seems that it hasn't been maintained since 2020 according to this: https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator/issues/111.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35740400)